# Create class according to type identifier

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there a design pattern, or any other way, for creating a class according to type?

My server receives a json message, containing an action to perform.

I have a several Action classes, that should be mapped to the corresponding class.

```
{ TYPE: 'MOVE' ... } => class ActionMove
{ TYPE: 'KILL' ... } => class ActionKill
```

(All Action classes implement Action interface).

How can I create the class according to the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to keep trace of your action instances (i.e. for logs), use the [Factory Pattern](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/):

```
public class ActionFactory{
    public Action createAction(String type){
        if (type.equals("MOVE"))
            return new ActionMove();
        if (type.equals("KILL"))
            return new ActionKill();
        ... // so on for the other types

        return null; //if the type doesn't have any of the expected values
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. but isn't the createAction method shouldn't be static ?

Comment: Yes you can set it as static, but in some cases you might also want to create an instance of `ActionFactory`.

Comment: I am sorry for my newbie knowledge but can you give example why I would like to have instance of ActionFactory, if its just used for creating objects?

Answer (score 2):

Create a HashMap mapping strings to Action objects:

```
Map<String,Action> map = new HashMap<String,Action>();

map.put("MOVE", new ActionMove());
map.put("KILL", new ActionKill());
```

And then get the prefered value:

```
Action a = map.get(type);
a.perform();
```

Or whatever you need.

---

If you're looking for classes with static methods, you can do reflection, but you're doing it wrong. You probably want to modify your code to use objects instead of classes.

Comment: I didn't explained myself currently. I meant object

Answer (score 0):

Ok ...

Thanks to your help I created a Factory method, which return an object according to type.

```
public class ActionFactory {
public static Action createAction(JSONObject object){

    try{
        String username = object.getString("USERNAME");         
        String type = object.getString("TYPE");
        String src= object.getString("SRC");
        String dest = object.getString("DEST");

        if(type == "MOVE"){
            return new ActionMove(username,src,dest);
        }
        else if(type == "KILL"){
            return new ActionKill(username,src,dest);
        }

        else if(type == "DIED"){
            return new ActionDied(username, src, dest);
        }
        else if(type == "TIE"){
            // TODO: implement
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;

}
```

}